# Setting Active Resource site dynamically at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeresource

I am stuck on how to set the site variable to ActiveResource at runtime, I read this post which explains how to do the same

http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/rails_modularity_1.html

But the only problem there is the mapping from service name to url is predefined. In my case its the same service except in different domain and return identical results.

```
domain1.mydomain.com
domain2.mydomain.com
```

This active resource belongs to another active record model and which domain to access depends on the attributes active record model retrieves from database. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it's pretty simple:

```
klass.site = "http://domain.com"
#make request
klass.site = "http://domain2.com
```

Comment: This can lead to race condition in production mode